# Why would a separate thread cause my UI to freeze?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, freeze

I'm starting a thread in my windows form application that tries to connect to a server and retrieve information from that server.

Meanwhile, I want my user to still be able to use his UI as normal.

But apparently that's not the case. If I can't connect to the server, the tread takes about 40 seconds before the attempt times out, and meenwhile, my UI remains frozen.

Note that the code of my UI process still runs. I can still reach breakpoints that happen after the thread was started.

The thread is simply started like this:

```
Public Sub NextRecord()
    Dim myThread As Thread
    myThread = New Thread(AddressOf ReadRecord)
    myThread.Start()
End Sub
```

I'm 100% certain it's the thread that freezes the UI and not some other logic, because if I comment out the call to NextRecord, the app runs no problem.

What could cause a thread to prevent the UI from running properly? How can I debug this? I've been trying to figure this out for a whole day now and I'm a bit desperate.

Edit:
tried something with interlocked but that was not the issue

Edit2: Here are some parts of the code I think might be relevant

First, my "ReadRecord" method. Its goal is to find a server that is reachable from a list of server, and try to read a valid line of data

```
'Reads a PLC record from the next available server in the list and updates the current server
Sub ReadRecord()

    ' If current state is busy then exit
    ' If 1 = Interlocked.Exchange(busy, 1) Then
    If busy = 1 Then
        Debug.Write("Trying to read, but another thread is already reading")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Interlocked.Exchange(busy, 0)
    busy = 1
    ' look for the first server with connected status
    For i = 0 To serverList.Count - 1
        Dim newIndex = (currentIndex + 1) Mod serverList.Count
        ' Interlocked.Exchange(currentIndex, newIndex) 
        currentIndex = newIndex
        Dim daServer As ADSServer = GetCurrentServer()
        ' Check the server status
        If GetAndUpdateServerStatus(daServer) Then '<----- this is where the freeze comes
            ' Check if the server is in tempo
            If daServer.IsInTempo() Then
                ' We can read from that server
                Dim record As PLCRecord
                record = daServer.ReadPLCRecord(tcads)
                If record.IsValid() Then
                    ' Stop the loop, because we read a valid record
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    'Release the lock
    ' Interlocked.Exchange(busy, 0)
    busy = 0
End Sub
```

The call to GetAndUpdateServerStatus attempts to connect to the server and updates its "alive" status

That method does a bit of variable checking and eventually calls the following method:

```
    Function OpenADSConnection(tcads As AxADSOCXLib.AxAdsOcx, Optional ByRef exception As String = "", Optional serverId As String = "", Optional port As String = "") As Boolean

    'first, make sure that we're not interfering with another connection
    If tcads.AdsAmsConnected Then
        exception = "OpenADSConnection - Connexion ADS déjà ouverte pour " & tcads.AdsAmsServerNetId & " Impossible d'ouvrir une nouvelle connexion pour " & serverId & " tant que la connexion n'est pas fermée."
        Return False
    End If

    tcads.AdsAmsServerNetId = IIf(serverId = "", My.Settings.adsServerId, serverId)
    tcads.AdsAmsServerPort = IIf(port = "", My.Settings.adsPort, port)
    tcads.AdsAmsConnect() '<---- this is an API call to connect to the server. tcads is an activeX control using microsoft COM (according to their doc) 

    If Not tcads.AdsAmsConnected Then
        exception = "OpenADSConnection - Impossible de se contecter au routeur ADS. Veuillez vérifier que TwinCat est bien installé sur cet ordinateur et que l'application est en train de tourner."
        Return False
    End If
    If tcads.AdsServerAdsState = "INVALID" Then
        exception = "OpenADSConnection - Aucun serveur d'automation n'est joignable à l'adresse " & tcads.AdsAmsServerNetId & "::" & tcads.AdsAmsServerPort
        Return False
    End If
    Return True

End Function
```

The specific line where the UI freezes, and that takes a bunch of seconds to execute is this one:

```
tcads.AdsAmsConnect()
```

Note that the tcads parameter is actually an AcviteX control that has to be added directly to the UI. I've tried to instantiate one through code, but it didn't work out. so esentially it's a reference to Me.tcads

The doc says the following about that control:

> The ADS-OCX provides methods, events and properties in order to be
>   able to exchange information with other ADS devices via the TwinCAT
>   Router. The ADS-OCX is implemented as an ActiveX control element, and
>   is based on Microsoft's COM technology.

Could it be that the UI thread doesn't like the fact that my connection thread is using one of its controls?

Comment: Are you doing anything on the UI with that thread? Have you tried just a background worker, what happens?

Comment: Please show us more code. We need to see what you're actually doing in the thread, how you start it is rarely relevant. Make sure to remove any instances of login credentials in your code before you post it.

Comment: I've added some relevant code

Comment: The UI probably hangs here   tcads.AdsAmsConnect()  You should get the data back from the thread then call your function. You could also create an new ADS object that is not on the UI. Any call made to it won't affect your UI thread

Comment: Problem is: I can't create a new ADS object just like that, it HAS to be a control on the UI.

But I've now changed my code a bit, to use a background worker instead of a thread. This way at least I can show an hourglass cursor while the connection attempt is happening. Still freezes the UI but at least the user knows there's something going on.

Comment: While the control must be instantiated and added in the UI thread, that doesn't stop you from calling its methods from a background thread as long as they don't try to modify the control _visually_. Have you tried running only `tcads.AdsAmsConnect()` in a background thread?

Comment: To me it doesn't look like any of the code inside your `OpenADSConnection()` function needs to actually run on the UI. I don't know that for sure, but it seems like the code is only doing "non-visual" stuff that doesn't change how the control looks or behaves.